# Build GNU make from source. Missing files on GIT repository

Tags: makefile, gnu-make, aix, configure

For a specific project, I have to build GNU make from source (in my case make 3.81) on AIX.
Everything was working fine while using official archive (https://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/make/make-3.81.tar.gz)

But then, I decided to use the GIT repository:

git clone --branch 3.81 https://git.savannah.gnu.org/git/make.git

And in this case, there is no "configure" script, contrary to the tar.gz archive.

There is no autoconf tool on my AIX, I intend to build it later, but first step is to build make.

Does someone know why the GIT repository doesn't provide exactly same content as the tar.gz archive ?

Regards.

Comment: First, GNU make 3.81 was released over 15 years ago and predates the use of Git.  The current Git repository was created by importing the historical code from CVS.  That's why there's no README.git file in that release.  Second, building make from source requires extra tools.  That's why the source tarballs exist: so that people without those extra tools can still build the source.  But if you want to build directly from the SCM tree not using the released package, you have to have all the extra tools available before you can build.

Answer (score 2):

> Everything was working fine while using official archive

That's the published version. It's the source release that's preconfigured to "just work".

> There is no autoconf tool on my AIX, I intend to build it later, but first step is to build make.

The Git repo is the development version, for use in a functioning development environment.

There's step-by-step instructions in [the README for the git install](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/make.git/tree/README.git) that tell you how to build from it. The very first step on that list is to install autoconf.

Comment: Thanks a lot. The README.git was not part of the 3.81 branch.